# Problems Solved by Primary Decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm looking for some examples of problems, possibly hard problems, which were solved with the use of primary decomposition. I am also looking for examples of its uses and where it provided further insights into the structure of rings. More detail if necessary.

Comment: You would do well to begin with the Wikipedia article on [Primary decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition).  Note the curious combination of names in the **Lasker-Noether theorem**.  Emanuel Lasker is now mainly remembered for his domination of championship chess, but he was accomplished as a research mathematician as well as at games other than chess.

Comment: "More detail if necessary."  Yes, that would be helpful.

Comment: I realize this question is quite general, so may be hard to answer -- thus the close votes. Maybe the following will motivate the question: I realized that primary decomposition can be dualized, so that every submodule of an Artinian module has a reduced "coprimary" decomposition. The uniqueness theorems also dualize. But I was trying to figure out what this could be useful for, and one place to start would be analogizing the places where primary decomposition is used.